# Head of department questionable comprehensive test decision

Tags: phd, ethics

I took the comprehensive test recently for my PhD and the head of the department sent me an email stating I didn't answer one of his questions the right way.  Now I answered the question exactly how it is written in the book he advised me to read and two of my fellow class mates answered the question exactly how it was written in the book and he had no problem with their answers, just mine.  In his email he stated to let him know if I wanted to meet with him to go over the question so I emailed him and his response was that he told me in the email what he wanted so there was no reason to meet.  I then responded and asked to meet with him anyway.  I have not received a response yet.  The thing is that this is a scientific textbook answer that is very precise and therefore cannot be misconstrued in any way so if he is the department head and he says it is wrong but it is black and white, what can I do with that?  What recourse do I have?  He could ruin my  academic career just because he is the department head and he says it is wrong.

Comment: Follow the academic grievance policy of your university. But in the meantime (the process takes time), start studying for your retake, presuming you get one in your program.

Answer (score 4):

If this is really such an unambiguous straightforward textbook-level question, how could two people disagree on the answer? The most likely explanation is that **one of them is making a mistake** (e.g. confused about the definition of one of the terms), and it's much more likely to be you than your professor, who has decades of experience in the field. These subtleties can be difficult to detect as a beginner, but often will be clear once one has some more experience.

I would first approach this situation from the ***assumption* that your professor is correct**, and try from that perspective to figure out how you could be wrong, even though you think your answer was directly from the textbook (and that it was the same as your classmates' answers). If you find your mistake, great.

If after devoting a good bit of effort to this, you can't find your mistake, I would write to the professor outlining what you've tried, and asking if they can explain in another way where your answer went wrong. If you can understand the issue at that point, great. (If not, you might try an older grad student. But I doubt it will get this far.)

To be clear: if the situation were *actually* exactly as you describe it, my response would be very different. But in my experience, 99% of such situations arise because the student has misunderstood the issue (just from inexperience, no fault of their own). In particular, filing any sort of academic grievance would likely be a huge over-reaction. I would never make such a move unless I had independent confirmation from a faculty member that I was correct.